# Does MDT (microsoft deployment toolkit) must work with WDS

Tags: windows, wds

I am new to system administration, and working in a small division where there is no Active Directory Domain Controllers. [The windows PCs are authenticated against Linux Samba domain controllers.] Currently windows OS are installed MANUALLY from a DVD, then manually install Office, configure this and that...

I am researching on a better way of windows deployment, and MDT, microsoft deployment toolkit seems very good and is free. However after viewing blogs and videos, I am still not sure if this tool can work on its own - does it rely on windows deployment service (WDS)? I am asking this because WDS seems to require active directory domain controllers, which we do not have.

IS there an automated Windows 7 installation solution that does not require AD Domain controllers? (I have to run the tool from my own windows 7, just like I am doing software updates on remote PCs from my PC using PDQ deploy...)

any input is welcome and thanked...

Answer (score 3):

Generally, WDS is only used to deploy the boot image. It does not host the install image in a typical MDT deployment. With the correct hackery, you can deploy this boot image and unattend file through something like `tftpd` and `pxelinux` rather than WDS, but it's totally unsupported and also a nightmare to set up.

You can always make a boot install CD instead of network booting. That would take all PXE out of the picture all together and alleviate the requirement for something like WDS.

Comment: And the boot CD you generate in MDT can be mounted, and then copied over to a bootable USB stick. Works great!